# Promises using nodejs and sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, q

Is there a way to avoid the nested chaining on the below code using 'q', any good way to use with promise ?

```
global.models.test.destroy({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }).then(function() {
        global.models.test1.findAll({
                attributes:[['id','testId']],
                include:[{
                    model: global.models.test2,
                    where: {
                        masterId: req.params.id
                    },
                    required: true
                }]
        }).then(function(app){
            var arrIds =[];
             for(var result in app){
                 var collection = app[result].dataValues;
                 arrIds.push(collection.id);
             }

             global.models.test1.destroy({
                where: {
                    id: arrIds
                }
             }).then(function() {
                 global.models.destroy({
                     // nested loops again and so on
                 }):
             })));
```

I am looking ways to clean up the code by avoiding the nested loops. All helps are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just return your promise from your `then`.

```
global.models.test.destroy({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id
    }
}).then(function() {
    return global.models.test1.findAll({
        attributes:[['id','testId']],
        include:[{
            model: global.models.test2,
            where: {
                masterId: req.params.id
            },
            required: true
        }]
    })
}).then(function(app) {
    var arrIds = [];
    for(var result in app) {
        var collection = app[result].dataValues;
        arrIds.push(collection.id);
    }
    return global.models.test1.destroy({
        where: {
            id: arrIds
        }
    });
}).then(function() {
    return global.models.destroy({
        //and so on
    });
});
```

I'd also avoid polluting the `global` variable.